# Angular 2+, a way to apply styles to the current component and all of it's child components?

Tags: css, angular, sass, shadow-dom

Reading through documentation for ViewEncapsulation, I'm not finding info that there is a nice way to apply styles for a component, and all of that component's child components. I'm a bit bewildered, as this seems like it would be a commonly employed technique, but the three options for ViewEncapsulation, Emulated, Native, None, don't appear to provide this feature.

My only options, as far as I can tell, are to either place the rules in the global styles (doesn't seem right, as I should be able keep my styles together with the component they pertain to), or repeat the rules within the component and each child component, which is a mess for maintainability.

Is this a missing feature, or am I missing something here?

Comment: You could create the style in the parent component folder and then for each child component simply reference the stylesheet on the @component decorator

Comment: That is a satisfactory solution in many cases, but it wont work where I want to apply rules to a component that is also used outside of my parent component, where I don't want those rules applied.

Comment: yes, you're missing something, Angular emulates web components with shadow root, and each component has its own shadow root, that's why styles aren't applied to children